# PDO 'Call to a member function prepare() on array'

Tags: php, pdo

Galera, sou novo no PDO e estou vendo algumas video aulas e também dando uma olhada na parte teorica, mas ao tentar realizar um `insert` no DB, está me retornando o seguinte erro `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on array in C:\FullProg\www\Thomas\prog\assets\inc\creat.php on line 19`.

O código está abaixo:

```
<?php 
// include_once 'conexao.php';
function getConnection(){
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db_name = "pdo";
    try{
        $conecta = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db_name, $user, $pass);
        return array("conexao" => $conecta, "mensagem" => "Sucesso");
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        return array("conexao" => null, "mensagem" => "Algo de errado não está certo. <br> Erro: " . $e -> getMessage());
    }
}
$conecta = getConnection();
$tipo = "Tipo";
$tamanho = "1M";
$nome = "Prod";
// $sql = "INSERT INTO produtos (nome, tamanho, tipo) VALUES (:nome, :tamanho, :tipo)";
// $stmt = $conecta->prepare($sql);
$stmt = $conecta->prepare("INSERT INTO produtos (nome, tamanho, tipo) VALUES (:nome, :tamanho, :tipo)");
$stmt->bindParam( ':nome', $nome );
$stmt->bindParam( ':tamanho', $site );
$stmt->bindParam( ':tipo', $tipo );
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Dados Salvos " . $nome;
}else{
    echo "Ocoreu um erro " . $nome;
}

?>
```

Já procurei no próprio doc que o php.net tem sobre e não consigo resolver isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque essa linha:

```
$stmt->bindParam( ':tamanho', $site );
```

por essa:

```
$stmt->bindParam( ':tamanho', $tamanho);
```

Comment: kkkkkkk não acredito que não vi que não existia mais a $site. vlw mano